# .addClass working on some classes but not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having trouble using the `.addClass` to `<div>` some tags.
It works fine on some and not at all on others.  Examples below.  Im wondering if certain things within the class effect it. I.E. `position:relative;` vs absolute, or having opacity already set in the class.

I am simply adding a class that reduces opacity to 0

SCRIPT

```
$(".ico_popup_container").addClass("ico_off");
```

CLASS TO BE ADDED:

```
.ico_off { 
    opacity:0;
}
```

When added to this it works fine:

```
.ico_container { 
    z-index:96;
    display:none;
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-size:cover;  
    background-position:100% 20%;   
    background-image:url(../images/ico/ico_back_01.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
}
```

When added to this it does NOT work:

```
.ico_popup_container { 
    z-index:95;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    width: 60%; 
    height:0%;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    opacity:1;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

I have tried removing the opacity and position tag to match settings of the one that works.  Still no results.  Maybe it has something to do with parent containers?

Comment: I'm confused, `.ico_popup_container` already has `opacity: 0` set, so what difference are you expecting `ico_off` to have

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to mention some JS turns opacity on before .addClass is applied

Comment: Did you give me a negative hit?

Answer (score 0):

Since ".ico_popup_container" already have "opacity: 0", then adding the class ".ico_off" wouldn't change anything on the page.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to mention some JS turns opacity on before .addClass is applied